# How to create dataframe from 2 dataframe if value exist in both dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 Pandas Dataframes with one column (ID).

the first one look like this:

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
```

and the second one look like this:

```
ID
3
4
5
6
7
```

I want to make a new Dataframe by combining those 2 Dataframes, but only the value that exist on both Dataframe.

This is the result that I want:

```
ID
3
4
5
```

can you show me how to do this in the most efficient way with pandas? Thank you

Comment: `inner` merge.... or `isin`

Comment: thanks! sorry if ask something that already asked before